# AngularJS: How to add dynamic slides to reveal.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, reveal.js

I am using [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/). Here is my code for creating slides:

```
  <div class="reveal">
                <div class="slides" ng-controller="myController">
                      <section>Slide1</section>
                      <section>Slide2</section>
                <div>
  <div>
```

Above code works fine.
Now in general case number of slides are not known and I need to create them dynamically. 
I used `ng-repeat` as below to create the slides but it didn't show anything. It seems that Angularjs  haven't finished rendering when reveal.js attempts to interpret the HTML into a slide.

`<section ng-repeat='silde in slides>...</section>`

I'm pretty new to Angularjs. Can you please give me suggestion for other solutions? How can I generate section tags in javascript and render them in html?